# Can we pass Cucumber Options values like Features and Tags values dynamically from TestNg.xml file?

Tags: cucumber, testng, cucumber-java, testng.xml

I am trying to run my regression test suite from TestNg.xml file. Most Testcases use different tags and different feature filenames. So i want to pass these input as a parameter from TestNg.xml file.

I currently have duplicate runner class with different combination of tags to handle this problem. Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. See Cucumber [TestNG - README md](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-testng#configure-cucumber-options-via-testng-xml).

Suppose you have a runner class like this:

```java
package com.example;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

public class RunCucumberTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

You can use it multiple times in `testng.xml`.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Example Suite">
    <parameter name="cucumber.filter.tags" value="@Gherkin and not @Zucchini" />
    
    <test name="Vegetable garden" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="cucumber.features" value="classpath:com/example/features/vegetable"/>
        <parameter name="cucumber.glue" value="com.example.vegetables.glue"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.RunCucumberTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    
    <test name="Herb garden" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="cucumber.features" value="classpath:com/example/features/herbs"/>
        <parameter name="cucumber.glue" value="com.example.herbs.glue"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.example.RunCucumberTests"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

For a list of properties see [Cucumber Core - README.md](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-core#cucumber-core).

Comment: For the above example, What should be mentioned in the Cucumber Option section "Feature" and "Tags" value?

Sample Code:

@CucumberOptions(features = "",
        glue = {"com.ABC.stepDef"}, monochrome = true, publish = true,
        tags = "", plugin = {"pretty", "pretty:target/cucumber-report/pretty.txt"})
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {}

Comment: Nothing at all. The properties you use in the XML are picked up by Cucumber from the test context here https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/cucumber-testng/src/main/java/io/cucumber/testng/AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java#L26

Answer (score 0):

It worked! I configured the test suite as below. Now I'm able to pass Cucumber Options values dynamically from the `TestNg.xml` file.

Cucumber Options Code:

```
@CucumberOptions(features="${cucumber.features}", glue={"com.CTC.stepDef"},monochrome=true,publish=true, tags="${cucumber.filter.tags}"}) publicclassRunMapperTestsextendsAbstractTestNGCucumberTests{} `
```

`TestNg.xml` file:

```
<suitename="AutomatedRegressionTestSuite">
<testname="VerifythattheTestcasesarevalid"> <parametername="cucumber.features"value="src/test/java/com/ABC/features/Apple.feature"/> 
<parametername="cucumber.filter.tags"value="@Regression"/> 
<classes> 
<classname="com.ABC.runner.RunRegressionTests"/> 
</classes> 
</test>
```

Comment: Those properties in the annotation don't actually do anything. Cucumber does not interpolate patterns. The values provided in the XML take precedence over those provided in the annotation https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/cucumber-testng/src/main/java/io/cucumber/testng/TestNGCucumberRunner.java#L88